# SharePoint 2010 debugging issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

4 team member is developing on a server. Now all 4 of them are debugging code for separate modules simultaneously. 
If one starts debugging others get trouble. How to solve this issue so that both can work simultaneously?

Comment: any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

Development is best performed on one server per developer. The four can develop without interfering with each other. When their done, upload solution to TFS and use a separate build server to be sure it always builds.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask each team member to take the local copy of the code from server and perform the operations of debugging. If all work simultaneousy, then they will get problems not only in debugging but in deploying the solutions.

So better to take the latest code from TFS, and make a local copy and go offline and then work.